# Running local environment with in create react-app displays %20?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently had to format my computer, but was given the option to save my files which I did. My project files are all there and good as far as I could tell. But when I do `npm start` it spins of the project without any errors, but then the URL bar displays this address:

> http://localhost:3000/pages%20/%20login%20-%20page

instead of:

> http://localhost:3000/pages/login-page

Note: This did not happen before I had to format my computer.

Steps I tried:

- Remove node modules, then run `npm i`
- Remove the %20 and hit enter, returns same thing in the URL bar

**index.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.css";
import Pages from "./layouts/Pages.jsx";
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from "./oldComp/actions/authActions";
import { clearCurrentProfile } from "./oldComp/actions/profileActions";
import store from "./oldComp/store";
import setAuthToken from "./oldComp/utils/setAuthToken";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import { indexRoutes } from "./routes/index.jsx";
import Profile from "./views/Community/ProfilePage/ProfilePage";
import { fetchAllLessons } from "./oldComp/actions/mentorLessonActions";
const hist = createBrowserHistory();
// Check for token
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  fetchAllLessons();
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    // Clear current Profile
    store.dispatch(clearCurrentProfile());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "/pages";
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hist}>
      <div>
        <Route path="/pages" name="Pages" component={Pages} />
        <Switch>
          {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
            return (
              <PrivateRoute
                path={prop.path}
                component={prop.component}
                key={key}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Switch>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute component={Profile} path="/partner-profile/:handle" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: If you go to http://localhost:3000/pages/login-page manually, does it redirect to the other URL? Maybe you could share your main `App` component. It's difficult to help without any code ( although I understand it's difficult to determine what code to include ).

Comment: I had a similar situation: When working on a certain computer, all AJAX requests failed, but only on that computer. On others, it worked. I tried deleting node_modules, etc, nothing worked. My ultimate solution was simply to use another browser. This may not be relevant to your problem, but it wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: It seems to be passing uri-encoded spaces. Maybe check your files for extra spaces?

Comment: @YannickK I included my index.js file

Comment: @tutiplain I tried it in another browser and it did the same thing =[

Comment: @pmkro I switched around my branches to see if I maybe types something in on my current branch on accident, but the other branches do the same.I'll keep that in mind while I dig at this.

Comment: Like pmkro said, %20 is a url-encoded space, I was thinking you might have some rogue spaces in your routes. Otherwise, I can't see anything else to be wrong unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched my files and had a redirect that had spaces in it.

This probably happened because I downloaded Beautify and it may have formatted some files that I wasn't aware of